# Unpredictable display of Facebook og:image

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We added Facebook Open Graph tags to our site NowGamer.com a few months back and everything worked perfectly initially. But in the last few weeks we've noticed that on about 2/3 of images the og:image would not display when an item was shared or liked. Sometimes going to the linter would scrape the page and the image would then be available.

But in other instances the image thumnbnail doesn't appear in the linter - although the link to the full image displays it at full size OK.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowgamer.com%2Fnews%2F1298151%2Fassassins_creed_3_join_or_die_freedom_collectors_editions_details.html

The images all fit within the 3:1 parameters although they are relatively large (they have to be as they are screenshots for video games). Here is an example of exactly the same type and size of image that *does* display in the Linter and on shares/Likes

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowgamer.com%2Fps3%2Fps3-reviews%2F1293635%2Fresident_evil_operation_raccoon_city_review.html

I can't see why one works and the other doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> The thumbnail's width AND height must be at least 50 pixels, and
>   cannot exceed 130x110 pixels.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Comment: Thanks for responding but that documentation applies to the deprecated Share button. The documentation for the Like button, and the open graph documentation, now only mentions the following:

"Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

As I mentioned - the second link to the Linter above shows an og:image of 1280x720  being displayed....

Comment: I did actually experience something similar on a bit more limited basis - but the images would then appear within 24 hours - it could be related to facebook caching

Answer (score 0):

Strange: I would have gone with a cache problem which I've also experienced before. For pure testing purposes if you want to attempt to refresh a different version of the URL try adding ?v=1 or some other parameter which makes the URL unique. This forces Facebook to go and get the URL again so you can make sure the images are working as expected.I think YouTube have also had this problem over the last few months http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/sharing-and-connecting-on-youtube/YnTqofAhcN8